# how can i count number of orders and then group them using case statements in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

so i have a table which looks like this:
[table image]

[image: 1]

and my desired output is this:
[my desired output image]

[image: 2]

Comment: I tried creating the table in the editor but was not able to, I am really sorry for the inconvenience, I am really new here with regards to posting questions

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

seems like a simple group by and count:

```
select cust_id , count(*) ordrnumber , concat('ordered ' , count(*),' time(s)') as group 
from table
group by cust_id
```

Comment: but how can I create the group column? i was trying case statements but it is not working

Comment: @DiganthSanghvi  you can make a string like this `concat('ordered ' , count(*),' times.`) as group ` but if you want the number to be in written format then you need another table to map numbers